# The diff tool in Visual Studio when using the Git Plugin

Tags: git, visual-studio, git-difftool

Microsoft has released a [Git plugin for Visual Studio 2012](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/63a7e40d-4d71-4fbb-a23b-d262124b8f4c).  I have found it to be excellent, but there doesn't seem to be any option to change the default Diff tool.  Worse, I cannot do a diff at all on ascx codebehind files.  It only shows a diff option for the main .ASCX file.

How do you

1. Diff the codebehind files when using the git plugin?
2. Change the diff tool?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You have to change your local .gitconfig, rather than make the change through Visual Studio as you would with TFS

https://gist.github.com/mkchandler/2377564

```
Add the following to your global .gitconfig file:

[diff]
    tool = diffmerge
[difftool "diffmerge"]
    cmd = \"C:\\Program Files\\SourceGear\\Common\\DiffMerge\\sgdm.exe\" \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\"
[merge]
    tool = diffmerge
[mergetool "diffmerge"]
    cmd = \"C:\\Program Files\\SourceGear\\Common\\DiffMerge\\sgdm.exe\" -merge -result=\"$PWD/$MERGED\" \"$PWD/$LOCAL\" \"$PWD/$BASE\" \"$PWD/$REMOTE\"
    trustExitCode = true
[mergetool]
    keepBackup = false
```

Comment: +1 Perfect-o!  This is exactly what I was looking for.  And lookie there, it opens up from command-line now too!

Comment: The .gitconfig is located in the User/[UserName]/ root folder as metioned in the link provided

Answer (score 15):

Steps :

1. Install Winmerge with "**WinMerge added to your PATH environment variable**", you have to select the check box during winmerge installation.
2. Microsoft GIT provider plugin should be installed in visual studio 2013.
3. Go to user git config, generally in "**C:\Users\USERNAME\.gitconfig**"
4. Add the following lines or update according to parameters inside .gitconfig

**

```
[diff]
    tool = winmerge
[difftool "winmerge"]
  cmd = winmergeu.exe -e -ub -x -wl -u -maximise -dl "base" -dr "mine" \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\"
[difftool]
  prompt = false
```

**

Now from Visual studio if you do "Compare with Unmodified..." on a file winmerge should open up automatically.

Comment: See [full list of winmerge command line arguments](http://manual.winmerge.org/Command_line.html) and [git's difftool command line variables](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-difftool#_options).