# Using Beyond Compare with Bitbucket extension for visual studio to see pull requests?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, bitbucket, beyondcompare

I'm using Visual studio 2017 professional with beyond compare as a diff/merge tool for our git (bitbucket) source code.

As you can see, BC is invoked I'm trying to compare with history :

[image]

I also wanted to see pull requests so I've installed the Bitbucket extension , and now I do see the additional button :

[image]

But when I click on the file in order to see the changes :

[image]

— Then I see the built-in  diff tool of windows :

[image]

**Question:**

How can I overwrite VS's default Diff tool, so that it will invoke Beyond-Compare , instead(!) of this default Diff tool?

Answer (score 0):

Does this link apply to your case ?

https://www.google.com/amp/www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2013/03/19/how-to-configure-diff-and-merge-tool-in-visual-studio-git-tools/amp/

> This happens because Visual Studio Git Plugin uses standard git configuration, your local repository probably does not have any specific tools for diff and merge (unless you configured them), so global settings are honored. To verify actual settings you can open a Git Bash on the repository, issue a git config –list command and look at merge.tool and diff.tool settings

This could be a configuration to be set a git/bit bucket repo level.
The link shows how to use the kdiff but I bet this could be done with beyond compare.

See also [The diff tool in Visual Studio when using the Git Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16674503/the-diff-tool-in-visual-studio-when-using-the-git-plugin) ?